# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.jdbc. Communications link failure in google cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm following the tutorial which is mentioned in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-recommendation-engine
during the step of "Find the best model" using bdutil I'm getting following error. I'm able to connect using cloud sql, created all necessary tables which are mentioned in the above link.

```
 gcloud beta sql connect unilogreco --user=root
```

I was able to connect using the above command

```
 /home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /home/jeevitesh_ms/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar --jars /home/jeevitesh_ms/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar find_model_collaborative.py 172.18.0.1 unilogreco root unilog123
```

When i check for error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.jdbc.: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Not finding relevant solution in google. hence kindly help me to resolve the issue

Snippet of error log

```
  17/10/24 20:06:19 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark/spark-warehouse/'.
17/10/24 20:06:21 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark/find_model_collaborative.py", line 59, in 
dfRates = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='Rating')
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 475, in jdbc
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in call
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.jdbc.
: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Complete Log

```
jeevitesh_ms@testmlrecommendation:~/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark$ /home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /home/jeevitesh_ms/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar --jars /home/jeevitesh_ms/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar find_model_collaborative.py 35.202.220.185 unilogreco root unilog123
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/10/24 20:57:48 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
17/10/24 20:57:48 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/10/24 20:57:48 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: app_collaborative
17/10/24 20:57:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jeevitesh_ms
17/10/24 20:57:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: jeevitesh_ms
17/10/24 20:57:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
17/10/24 20:57:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
17/10/24 20:57:48 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(jeevitesh_ms); groups with view permissions: Set(); users with modify permissions: Set(jeevitesh_ms); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 56068.
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-aff00f6d-085c-4b22-b853-8a122f59dab1
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 413.9 MB
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://172.17.0.2:4040
17/10/24 20:57:49 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/jeevitesh_ms/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar at spark://172.17.0.2:56068/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar with timestamp 1508858869966
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark/find_model_collaborative.py at spark://172.17.0.2:56068/files/find_model_collaborative.py with timestamp 1508858870271
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO Utils: Copying /home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark/find_model_collaborative.py to /tmp/spark-b4e50762-1ad8-40bd-afcc-7506d7001573/userFiles-33652ea8-5749-42da-b9b5-ff92f2951c3b/find_model_collaborative.py
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://172.17.0.2:7077...
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /172.17.0.2:7077 after 28 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20171024205750-0007
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 52228.
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 172.17.0.2:52228
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.17.0.2, 52228, None)
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 172.17.0.2:52228 with 413.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 172.17.0.2, 52228, None)
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.17.0.2, 52228, None)
17/10/24 20:57:50 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 172.17.0.2, 52228, None)
17/10/24 20:57:51 INFO EventLoggingListener: Logging events to file:/tmp/spark-events/app-20171024205750-0007
17/10/24 20:57:51 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
17/10/24 20:57:51 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark/spark-warehouse/').
17/10/24 20:57:51 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark/spark-warehouse/'.
17/10/24 20:57:52 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark/find_model_collaborative.py", line 59, in 
dfRates = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='Rating')
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 475, in jdbc
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in call
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.jdbc.
: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  jeevitesh_ms@testmlrecommendation:~/spark-recommendation-engine-master/pyspark$ /home/jeevitesh_ms/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit   --driver-class-path /home/jeevitesh_ms/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.j
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2017)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelatio)
```

please help to solve this issue